# Need to create RLS in Powerbi, for different managers with different permission level

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I am currently trying to create an RLS where regional manager can only access data by the region filter and country manager can only access data by the country filter. I have tried creating roles on PowerBI desktop but every time i select country manager to only view data by country and I go to view as and then select country manager, nothing happens, it doesn't give me countries options in the filters. An example of what I did is as below -

Manage Roles > Then i Created two roles which i called country manager and region manager, In the Tables, i chose country profile table, add filters and select Country for the country manager. In the Table filter DAX expression, i used the DAX code: [Country] = TRUE ().

The above dax doesn't seem to be working, but if i was to use [Country] = "Germany". it works and gives me Germany, but how can i make it show all countries when viewing country manager.

i tried create different dax, i aslo consider a page level security, but there's not what i am looking for

Comment: Country manager can view all the countries? If so then change the DAX to just `TRUE()`

Comment: doesn't work, i can't post pictures, i was going to post the error i am getting

Comment: Share a link to sample PBIX (via OneDrive, Google Drive, DropDox, etc...)